# how to change the form properties in client-side using server-side C#

Tags: c#, sockets, client-server

I have server-client application that communicates over a simple string protocol using sockets, i would like to change the properties of any object in client side form by interacting with the server.

For example:

The **server side form** has button named `btnMaximizeClient` that will maximize client's window

The **client side form** should maximize itself when `btnMaximizeClient` on the server-side is pressed.

thank you in advance

Comment: There is no silver bullet for this.  Do you already have a protocol defined for your client/server to communicate over.  What have you tried?

Comment: yes i already defined everything, i can send/receive strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple solution to get you rolling:

Create an event in the client's socket listener:

```
public event string MessageReceived;
```

When a new string comes through, do any processing that is necessary and then raise the event:

```
MessageReceived(this, "MaximizeWindow")
```

Then create a listener in your ClientForm

```
SocketListenerClassInstance.MessageReceived += OnMessageReceived;
```

and process those messages with a method in your ClientForm:

```
void OnMessageReceived(object sender, string msg)
{
    if (msg.Equals("MaximizeWindow")
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
```